# C Reader Writer Mutexes for a Copying a File using Shared Memory and Ring Buffer

Tags: c, ubuntu

I want to build a File Copier using Reader-Writer Synchronization Paradigm.
The Writer initializes the both of the Mutexes. The FullMutex is denoting how many Buffers are available to Write and the FreeMutex is denoting how many Buffers are available to Read.
The Writer waits when the Block is Full.
The WritePointer and ReadPointer is using the Ring Buffer. Therefore I have used Mod Operation.
The Block Size=M.
The Buffer Size=B.
There are N number of Buffers.
So, M=N*B.
The File Size=2M.
And therefore BufferCount is actually advancing File Pointer.
When all Bytes are written, I am issuing FileEnding=1.

The compilation commands are-

```
g++ Writer.c -o Writer -lpthread -lrt
g++ Reader.c -o Reader -lpthread -lrt
```

And in 2 different comand prompts are open and the commands are issued-

```
./Writer
./Reader
```

Now I do not know why it is not copying and do not know how to use sem_post.
Here is the Writer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    struct MemData{
        sem_t FullMutex;
        sem_t FreeMutex;
        char FileName[128];
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        int FileEnding;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    //int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    int BufferSize=2;//EXPERIMENATION
    unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];
    int BufferCount=0;

    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fchmod(SD, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    if(ftruncate(SD, sizeof(MemData))< 0){
        printf ("ftruncate() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        sem_init(&M->FullMutex, 1, 0);
        sem_init(&M->FreeMutex, 1, NumberOfBuffers);
        strcpy(M->FileName, "aaa.txt");
        M->FileEnding=0;
        M->ReadPointer=0;
        M->WritePointer=0;
        memset(M->Data, '\0', strlen(M->Data));
    }
    char FileName[128]="aaa.txt";
    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "rb");
    if(FP!= NULL){
        struct stat StatBuf;
        if(stat(FileName, &StatBuf)==-1){
            printf("failed to fstat %s\n", FileName);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        long long FileSize=StatBuf.st_size;
        printf("\nFile Size: %lld", FileSize);
        long long FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        long long CopyableMemorySize=FileSize-FilePosition;
        printf("\nCopyable File Size: %lld", CopyableMemorySize);
        int NumberOfFileBuffers=CopyableMemorySize/BufferSize;
        printf("\n Number Of File Buffers: %d", NumberOfFileBuffers);
        while(1){
            sem_wait(&M->FreeMutex);
            fseek(FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
            fread(Buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
            int FreeMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FreeMutex, &FreeMutexValue);
            int FullMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FullMutex, &FullMutexValue);
            printf("\nMutexes-Free: %d and Full: %d", FreeMutexValue, FullMutexValue);
            printf("\nBuffer Writing: %s", BufferCount);
            memcpy(&M->Data[M->WritePointer*BufferSize], &Buf, sizeof(Buf)*sizeof(unsigned char));
            BufferCount++;
            M->WritePointer=(M->WritePointer+1)%NumberOfBuffers;
            if(BufferCount>=NumberOfFileBuffers && M->WritePointer==M->ReadPointer){
                M->FileEnding=1;
                break;
            }
            sem_post(&M->FullMutex);
        }
        fclose(FP);
    }
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

The Reader is using the Mutex opened by the Writer.c.
All the Block Size, Buffer Size and Number of Buffers are same like the Writer.c.
When the Reader gets FileEnding==1, it breaks the loop since there is nothing to process.
The Reader destroy the Mutex and deallocates Memory.

Here is the Reader.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    char FileName[128]="bbb.txt";
    struct MemData{
        sem_t FullMutex;
        sem_t FreeMutex;
        char FileName[128];
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        int FileEnding;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    //int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    int BufferSize=2;//EXPERIMENATION
    unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];
    int BufferCount=0;
    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n"); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "wb");
    if(FP!= NULL){
        while(1){
            sem_wait(&M->FullMutex);
            int FreeMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FreeMutex, &FreeMutexValue);
            int FullMutexValue;
            sem_getvalue(&M->FullMutex, &FullMutexValue);
            printf("\nMutexes-Free: %d and Full: %d", FreeMutexValue, FullMutexValue);
             printf("\nBuffer Writing: %d", BufferCount);
            printf("\nReadPointer: %d", M->ReadPointer);
            printf("\nWritePointer: %d", M->WritePointer);
            fseek(FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
            fseek(FP, BufferCount*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&M->Data[M->ReadPointer*BufferSize], sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
            BufferCount++;
            M->ReadPointer=(M->ReadPointer+1)%NumberOfBuffers;
            if(M->FileEnding){
                fclose(FP);
                break;
            }
            sem_post(&M->FreeMutex);
        }
    }
    munmap(M,sizeof(MemData));
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

The input(aaa.txt) file contains these lines-

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

The output(bbb.txt) file contains these lines-

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: Why two programs to do one thing? I hope this is a learning exercise

Comment: @BugSquasher, it is a Synchronization Problem.

Comment: Which has already been solved by every major os why do it again, and in such an inefficient manner? Shared memory between two processes is not needed.

Comment: To be more useful, I think you have a race condition in the memdata struct M because the data in the struct itself is not guarded by a mutex. That would explain the different files at least. I'll have to look at your code more in depth tomorrow.

Comment: @BugSquasher, yes.